# Group recommendation system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recommendation-engine

In our application, we have users who can create or join a group. Currently we want to build a recommendation system in which given a group & the group members compute non-members of the group who might be interested in joining the group. We assume that we can calculate the interests based on the other groups of the group members.

Please point me in the right direction. We are using rails & mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into implementations of the [collaborative memory-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering#Memory-Based) algorythm; where your matrix will hold the users and their groups to find similar but new members based on their other groups. More info - [Writing a basic recommendation engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051965/writing-a-basic-recommendation-engine?rq=1)